# FileStream Promise resolving early

Tags: node.js, promise, stream

I am experiencing a rather weird problem in nodeJS, and I cannot quite figure out why.

Consider the following code:

```js
(async () => {
    console.log ("1");

    await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout (() => {
            console.log ("2");
            resolve ();
        }, 1000);
    });

    console.log ("3");
    process.exit ();
})();
```

This code does exactly what it is supposed to do. It prints `123`, in that order. After the print of `1`, it waits approximately one second. Perfect. Now let's see the following example:

```js
const fs = require ("fs");

(async () => {
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream ("file.txt");
    stream.write ("Test");

    console.log ("1");

    await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on ("finish", () => {
            console.log ("2");
            resolve ();
        });
    });

    console.log ("3");
    process.exit ();
})();
```

From my understanding, this code should either complete, or - in case the `finish` event never gets fired - run infinitely. What happens is the exact opposite: It prints `1`, then quits. Shouldn't it *at least* print another `3` before quitting, since this is the end of the script?

**Important: I know that the promise will not resolve, because `.end()` is not called on the stream. I want to know why the script finishes anyway.**

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: `"end"` is the event usually. Also kind of bad practice to do that. If you must wrap event handlers in a Promise, then create the instance and register all handlers "inside" the wrapping Promise instead.

Comment: Actually, writable streams need the `finish`-event while readable streams need the `end`-event, so that should not be the problem here.

Comment: Sorry read that in reverse. I see your misunderstanding in that you seem to think things wait until you actually close the file handle explicitly. They do not.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding you here. The promise should wait until it is resolved. It is never resolved, otherwise, we would see `2` printed beforehand. Why does the script exit without waiting for the promise?

Comment: Nope. Read my answer, hopefully it's a reasonable demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best explanation is probably to write this without the `async/await` keywords and for you to undertstand these don't do anything "magical" and are simply "sugar" for a different way to resolve a Promise as opposed to `.then()`.

```
const fs = require ("mz/fs");

const stream = fs.createWriteStream("file.txt");
stream.write("Test");

console.log("1");

new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on ("finish", () => {
        console.log("2");
        resolve();
    });
}).then(() => {
   console.log("2");
   process.exit();
});
```

That's the exact same thing right! So where's the catch.

The thing you are really missing is there is "nothing" that says when you open a file handle it **"must"** be explicitly closed before the program can exit. As such, there is "nothing to wait for" and the program completes but does not "branch" into the part that is still awaiting the `Promise` to `resolve()`.

The reason why it only logs `"1"` is because the remaining branch "is" waiting for the Promise to resolve, but it's just never going to get there before the program finishes.

Of course that all changes when you actually call `stream.end()` immediately after the `write` or ideally by "awaiting" any write requests that may be pending:

```
const fs = require ("mz/fs");

(async () => {
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream ("file.txt");
    await stream.write ("Test");          // await here before continuing
    stream.end()
    console.log ("1");

    await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on ("finish", () => {
            console.log ("2");
            //resolve ();
        });
    });

    console.log ("3");
    //process.exit ();
})();
```

That of course will log each output in the listing, as you should well know.

So If you were expecting to see the `"3"` in the log, the reason why it does not is because of the `await` where we don't ever close the stream. Again probably best demonstrated by getting rid of the `await`:

```
const fs = require ("mz/fs");

(async () => {
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream ("file.txt");
    await stream.write ("Test");
    stream.end()
    console.log ("1");

    new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {    // remove await - execution hoisted
        stream.on ("finish", () => {
            console.log ("2");
            //resolve ();
        });
    });

    console.log ("3");
    //process.exit ();
})();
```

Then you "should" see:

```
1
3
2
```

At least on most systems unless you have an "extreme" lag. But generally the `"finish"` should get fired before the next line was reached after "awaiting" the `write`.

---

> **NOTE**: Just using the [`mz`](https://github.com/normalize/mz) library here for demonstration of an an `await` on the `write()` method without wrapping a callback. Generally speaking the callback execution *should* resolve just the same.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Does that mean that when a promise does not resolve, the program will simply exit once it has nothing more to do instead of waiting an infinite amount of time?

Comment: @NikxDa It depends on what is happening. For instance a `http` server is actually still listening for things on the event loop, or "reading" a file is waiting for the end of file.  Such things would mean the program would not exit until either of those things stop. But there is nothing that says your opened file for writing needs to complete. Or indeed that the `Promise` itself has to resolve before completion. If it's like this case, it simply gets discarded.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that makes sense! I thought `Promise`s would simply wait for a resolve, no matter what.

Comment: @NikxDa This is why I began the explanation "without" using the `await` keyword. The common misconception is that this keyword tells everything to "halt". This is not "covert to synchronous" magic. Simply a different way of writing `.then()`, and cleaner to. But often misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks for your help!